Frontend Controller drops 404
I created a module for Craft to get a simple contact form.
To create the module I used the make module command.
Now my problem is, that the controller is not found and I get a 404 message when I submit the form.
In the log I get the following response:
2024-12-23 11:23:21 [web.ERROR] [Error] Class "Craft\web\Controller" not found {"trace":["#0 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(576): include()","#1 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(427): Composer\\Autoload\\{closure}('/var/www/html/v...')","#2 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('modules\\\\contact...')","#3 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(661): class_exists('modules\\\\contact...')","#4 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(620): yii\\base\\Module->createControllerByID('contact')","#5 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(612): yii\\base\\Module->createController('send')","#6 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(546): yii\\base\\Module->createController('contact/send')","#7 /var/www/html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(304): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('contact/contact...', Array)","#8 /var/www/html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(607): craft\\web\\Application->runAction('contact/contact...', Array)","#9 /var/www/html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(283): craft\\web\\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\\web\\Request))","#10 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\\web\\Request))","#11 /var/www/html/web/index.php(12): yii\\base\\Application->run()","#12 {main}"],"memory":2300368,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"Craft\\web\\Controller\" not found at /var/www/html/modules/contact/controllers/ContactController.php:9)"} 


My setup:

modules

contact

Contact.php
controllers

FormController.php







app.php
'modules' => [
        'contact' => Contact::class,
    ],

routes.php
return [
    'contact' => 'contact/contact/send',
];

FormController.php
namespace modules\contact\controllers;

use Craft;
use Craft\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;

class FormController extends Controller {
    protected array|int|bool $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionSend():Response {
        $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();

        Craft::info('Sending contact request', __METHOD__);

...
}

contact.twig
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="wrap contact-form" id="contact-form">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('contact/contact/send') }}

    <h3><label for="from-name">Ihr Name</label></h3>
    {{ input('text', 'fromName', submission.fromName ?? '', {
        id: 'from-name',
        autocomplete: 'name',
    }) }}
...

I read all about Craft controllers, modules, yii Framework controllers - from my perspective, it should work. I appreciate your help.
Have a great Christmas and a Happy new Year:
Kind regards
Florian
